# Java: how to execute easily a program in an other computer?

Tags: java

I need to execute the program I've written in Java in another computer different from mine. Is there a way to make it run without having to set the system and enviroment variables and without having to compile it manually through the shell? It would be great if I could just click on a file and make it run. Thank you

Comment: Java is designed for platform independency. As long as you have valid Java bytecode and a standard VM, your code can execute.

Comment: We'll since its java you shouldn't have to recompile it as long as you're using the same java version on each machine.  Are you on a linux box? And if your program uses env vars then they're going to have to be set in order for it to run.

Answer (score 1):

Create a runnable jar. If the user has his Java set up properly, it can be run by double clicking on the jar.

(Provided of course that you don't make it depend on paths or other things on your particular computer).